# ¿Cómo activar las sugerencias de auto completado con un atajo de teclado en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode, configuración, autocompletar, atajo

Siempre que escribo código en Visual Studio Code, en cada palabra me sale una ventana pequeña sugiriendo un autocompletado (En la mayoría) y me gustaría saber si alguien sabe cómo configurar para que la ventana de autocompletado *aparezca con un atajo de teclado* y **no de forma automatica**. En el entorno de desarrollo Netbeans es así, con el atajo Control+espacio aparecen las sugerencias de autocompletado.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo de configuración `settings.json` coloca:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions.other": false
```

Esto va a desactivar las sugerencias. Por defecto puedes disparar el autocompletado presionando `Ctrl` + `.`. Puedes ver más opciones para personalización en la [documentación oficial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense).

Comment: Lo hice, pero me dice lo siguiente: "Parámetro de configuración desconocido"